Provisioning Windows Driver Kit fails due to unclear error
I am trying to set up a "target" PC for Windows kernel driver deployment and debugging, and have meticulously followed all the steps here  and here.
I am at the Provisioning step now and am trying the automatic Provisioning in Visual Studio, like so:

It fails with the following errors, however:
...
Progress event: Current: 14, Max: 17, Message: "Configuring TAEF test service to start automatically"
[14:10:37:131]: Configuring TAEF test service to start automatically
[14:10:37:131]: [Configuring TAEF test service to start automatically] Command Line:
sc config Te.Service start= auto
Task result status updated: Pass
Task result status updated: Pass
[14:10:37:231]: Task "Configuring TAEF test service to start automatically" completed successfully
Progress event: Current: 14, Max: 17, Message: "    Task "Configuring TAEF test service to start automatically" completed successfully"
Result completed
Test process exit code: 0
Progress event: Current: 15, Max: 17, Message: "Configuring kernel debugger settings (possible reboot)"
[14:10:37:246]: Configuring kernel debugger settings (possible reboot)
[14:10:37:246]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder.
[14:10:37:262]: Copying required files for "Configuring kernel debugger settings (possible reboot)".
[14:10:37:832]: [Configuring kernel debugger settings (possible reboot)] Command Line:
$KitRoot$\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\MinTE\te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_ConfigureKernelDebugger'" /p:"DebugTransport=NET" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"NetHost=169.123.456.789" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"NetPort=50000" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"NetKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"StartPolicy=Active" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"IgnoreUserModeExceptions=0" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"SuppressReboot=1" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\Configuring_kernel_debugger_settings_(possible_reboot)_00000.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[14:10:37:886]: Task "Configuring kernel debugger settings (possible reboot)" was aborted because an error occured on the target machine during execution.

An error occurred on the target machine while executing a process.
Error code: 3
Error message: Unable to start process
Progress event: Current: 15, Max: 17, Message: "    Task "Configuring kernel debugger settings (possible reboot)" was aborted because an error occured on the target machine during execution.

An error occurred on the target machine while executing a process.
Error code: 3
Error message: Unable to start process"
Task result status updated: Aborted
Result completed
Test process exit code: 0
Progress event: Current: 16, Max: 17, Message: "Configuring computer settings (possible reboot)"
[14:10:37:917]: Configuring computer settings (possible reboot)
[14:10:37:917]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder.
[14:10:37:917]: Copying required files for "Configuring computer settings (possible reboot)".
[14:10:38:503]: [Configuring computer settings (possible reboot)] Command Line:
$KitRoot$\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\MinTE\te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_ConfigureCommonSettings'" /p:"OsSkuType=0" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\Configuring_computer_settings_(possible_reboot)_00000.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[14:10:38:565]: Task "Configuring computer settings (possible reboot)" was aborted because an error occured on the target machine during execution.

An error occurred on the target machine while executing a process.
Error code: 3
Error message: Unable to start process
Progress event: Current: 16, Max: 17, Message: "    Task "Configuring computer settings (possible reboot)" was aborted because an error occured on the target machine during execution.
...

Upon inspection, it is clear that the issue is the following command:
$KitRoot$\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\MinTE\te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_ConfigureKernelDebugger'" /p:"DebugTransport=NET" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"NetHost=169.123.456.789" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"NetPort=50000" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"NetKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"StartPolicy=Active" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"IgnoreUserModeExceptions=0" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"SuppressReboot=1" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\Configuring_kernel_debugger_settings_(possible_reboot)_00000.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
Also if I run this command manually on the target PC, it indeed fails, but it is clearer on what fails: it says it can't generate this output log file. If I run the following command (i.e. removed all output settings) it succeeds fine!!
$KitRoot$\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\MinTE\te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_ConfigureKernelDebugger'" /p:"DebugTransport=NET" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"NetHost=169.123.456.789" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"NetPort=50000" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"NetKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"StartPolicy=Active" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"IgnoreUserModeExceptions=0" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /p:"SuppressReboot=1" /p:"TestHarness=ERT" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging
So the question is: is there any way to make this work, either by fixing the real issue (no idea what that is), or by simply having Visual Studio call the same thing but without output files?

I've always found the Visual Studio driver deployment to be brittle/finicky. It's not too hard to just copy the binaries to the machine manually.

Yes that's the option I'm stuck with for now, but it's definitely adding to the already slow iteration cycle. But more importantly, this step is required for "Enable Driver Verification"

"it says it can't generate this output log file", can you provide exact error?
